# Single page archive - get coresponding taxonomy and terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

For custom post type i have 12 taxonomies (12 months) and each of them with many terms (plant parts - roots, leaves, flowers etc.)
On archive page i retrieve a data list with this

```
foreach($months as $month) :
    $args = array(  'post_type' => 'branje_biljaka', 'posts_per_page' => 100,
            'tax_query' => array( array(
                'taxonomy' => $month,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $plant_parts
            )
        )
    );
$branje = new WP_Query( $args );
```

and it works perfectly. On a single archive page I am stuck.
I don't know how to fetch any corresponding data other than the_title() but I need to fetch the same data for every month and all plant parts but only for that specific post.

I dont have any 'normal' data to echo like the_content, only those terms. I think I am complicating this more than I should and I believe Wordpress does this with much less work... but how do I expand the same query so it grabs only current single archive post title? Everything else should be the same...

Inserting something like 'ID' => get_the_ID() into arguments does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm i got it working with

```
has_term
```

So the code is...

```
$data = [];
foreach($months as $key => $val) :
    $data[$key][$val] = [];
foreach($parts as $part) {

    if( has_term( $part, $key ) ) {
        array_push($data[$key][$val], $part);
    }   
}
endforeach;
```